# Passing Json::Value to a function in C++ dll is throwing read access violation exception

Tags: c++, json, dll, dllexport, jsoncpp

I am using JsonCPP library in my C++ project . I created a C++ dll with a function which will take Json::Value as input parameter . I have created another one exe which calls this function by passing Json::Value as argument. Inside the dll function, while reading this json value , it throws read access violation exception .

I was passing string as well which used to give error . I changed string to char* which resolves my problem . But I don't know how to handle passing json value .

below is the example code snippet .

C++ dll :

```
foo(json::value jsonValue)
{
auto value = jsonValue["name"];
}
```

another exe:

I linked dll with this exe project . And while debuging I can go inside foo function . so there is no problem in loading dll and calling function .

I am reading json from my local json file and storing it in jsonValue.

```
json::value jsonValue = readFromLocalFile();

cout<<jsonValue["name"];    // works well

foo(jsonValue);             // goes inside foo function and breaks wile reading jsonValue["name"]
```

I am using visual studio 2019 to build both the projects .

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFPXV.png)

Can anyone please help me with this error .

Comment: How are you building the code? How are the dll and executable linked to jsoncpp? Are they both using the same visual studio runtime?

Comment: I am using json.h & json.cpp directly in my project . I am building the code with visual studio 2019 . Both the projects are under same solution . I gave dll project as reference in exe project .

Comment: So the dll and the exe both compile json.cpp? I'd guess there's some static data in there which doesn't get shared between them.

Comment: yeah , I have included json.h and json.cpp separately in both the projects and compiled them together .

Comment: I removed json.h and json.cpp from both the projects. Now #include<json.h> referred from vcpkg for both the projects.  now I can pass json from one project to other project , and can read values without crashing . but if I do jsonValue.asString() , I am not getting correct string value . If I do cout<<jsonValue["name"], this print the correct output . but not storing value as string . I don't know where I am going wrong . can you help .